# Multi Output Regression to Compare the Difference of the Network Outputs

Tags: python, keras, regression

I would like to build a network with Keras / Tensorflow, where I read in several features and receive two outputs (actual value/setpoint).
I would like to compare these to determine whether they exceed a specified threshold.

Does anyone have experiences/tips with such a regression model?